# Only the first of two consecitive binding elements gets rendered

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I don't understand why the second item here doesn't rendered,ie just one p gets output ..:

```
   <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: Foos">
       <div class="three columns">
           <p data-bind="text: CriteriaStub"></p>
           <p data-bind="text: CriteriaStub"></p>
       </div>
       <div class="three columns">
           <!--this gets rendered fine-->
           <p data-bind="text: Baa"></p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

It only seems to happen for consecitive binding elements.

View model item for the foreach:

```
var Foo= (function () {
    function Foo(jsonObject) {
        var self = this;

        self.AdHocRecipients = ko.observableArray(jsonObject.AdHocRecipients);
        self.CriteriaStub = ko.computed(function () {

            return "No criteria";
        });

        self.AdHocRecipientsToStringStub = ko.computed(function () {
            var stub = "";
            for(var i in self.AdHocRecipients()) {
                stub += (self.AdHocRecipients()[i].User) + ', ';
            }
            return self.AdHocRecipients().length > 0 ? stub.slice(0, -2) : "No recipiants";
        });
        var t = 2;
    }
    return Foo;
})();
```

Parent:

```
var ViewModel = (function () {
    function ViewModel(json) {

        var parsedFoos = new Array();
        for(var i in json.Foos) {
            parsedFoos.push(new Foo(json.Foos[i]));
        }
        this.Foos = ko.observableArray(parsedFoos);
    return ViewModel;
})();
```

Comment: What's your view model?

Comment: Ah, I was thinking more of the parent view model!

Comment: sure, I've been debugging everything and the view models look fine, they just don't render the 2nd thing. Also in the for each self.CriteriaStub renders but self.AdHocRecipientsToStringStub throws a Message: ReferenceError: AdHocRecipientsToStringStub is not defined; Again they log fine when checking in the Debugger

Comment: hmm            <p data-bind="text: CriteriaStub"></p>
            <p data-bind="text: CriteriaStub"></p>  seems to work now. its just the AdHocRecipientsToStringStub  is giving me trouble..

Comment: I put your example in a jsFiddle and it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/7wzk2/  Check your console to see if you have some errors being thrown from your JS Code.  I also advise you *not* to use `for (var i in someArray)`.  That leads to trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know for sure, but the only thing that stands out as potentially wrong is that Foo is a self-executing function that also returns itself. I don't see what that gets you when you are calling it multiple times. Have you tried just having Foo as a function?

```
function Foo(jsonObject) {
    var self = this;

    self.AdHocRecipients = ko.observableArray(jsonObject.AdHocRecipients);
    self.CriteriaStub = ko.computed(function () {

        return "No criteria";
    });

    self.AdHocRecipientsToStringStub = ko.computed(function () {
        var stub = "";
        for(var i in self.AdHocRecipients()) {
            stub += (self.AdHocRecipients()[i].User) + ', ';
        }
        return self.AdHocRecipients().length > 0 ? stub.slice(0, -2) : "No recipiants";
    });
    var t = 2;
}
```

Also, be careful with your html tags. Whilst I think that self-closing tags are generally valid, they don't always work, so use  rather than .

Comment: Not really because the js is rendered via typescript which I don't think is friendly to the knockout codebase. I also find that the order effects it, eg  <button data-bind="click: $parent.openDialogueEdit">Edit</button>
            <span data-bind="    text: CriteriaStub" />
renders both

where as this renders the first item only

            <span data-bind="    text: CriteriaStub" />
             <button data-bind="click: $parent.openDialogueEdit">Edit</button>

Comment: Is that because you've not got the full closing tag for span? Things can get a bit funny when you don't have proper closing tags sometimes, even though it should be valid.

Comment: Html can be a right pain sometimes! I'll add that to the answer, in case anyone else ends up here.

Comment: The self executing function is fine.  It only executes once to assign the global Foo variable.  All the calls to `new Foo(...)` then use this global Foo variable.  This is standard JS module coding to hide private variables within a closure.

Comment: Sure, I get that, but I don't get what advantage it confers in this specific example, and nothing else looked wrong in the question, so I was clutching at straws!